# XSLT Relative path from absolute path

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

How do I extract the path to the root folder of a given file?

I have the expression

```
path/to/one/of/my/file.xml
```

I must get

```
../../../../../
```

using XSLT/XPath ?

Comment: The number of slashes is unknown and I'm using XSLT 1.0

Comment: So you want `path` if the path is `path/to/one/of/my/file.xml`?

Comment: I think the relative path you want is `../../../../` not `../../../../../` -- either you or I have committed an off-by-one error.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [`fn:tokenize`](https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xslt/xslt-und-xpath-referenz/alphabetische-liste/tokenize/) is an XPath 2.0 function, you have to use a recursive template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- initial call with path to tokenize -->
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
      <xsl:with-param name="str" select="'path/to/one/of/my/file.xml'" />
    </xsl:call-template>    
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- recursive named template -->      
  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="str" />
    <xsl:param name="result" select="''" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="substring-after($str,'/')">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring-after($str,'/')" />
          <xsl:with-param name="result" select="concat($result,'../')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$result" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
../../../../../
```